# "as" and "that" interchangeability

Tags: relative-clauses, comparisons, relative-pronouns

This is a sentence from a piece of technical writing I am reviewing, penned by a British author, and I can't help but want to change "that" to "as".

> That word still means the same thing here in the U.K. **that** it does in the U.S., when used in the context of engineering.

A certain degree of interchangeability does exist between "as" and "that" ([this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/36789) is tangentially related but not conclusively to my question) but I am not 100% sure it works in this context. "A means the same thing here which it does (means) there" seems to work with "which/that" being the object of "to mean" in the relative clause. So (the sentence was written with "as") would "as" be a relative pronoun here? And can "that" replace "as" in this sentence? More generally when are "as" and "that" interchangeable in a "the same" construct?

Comment: Be brave. Slash and burn as needed and edit as little as you must, that your results be smooth as silk for the reader, not the author. *As* is no pronoun for you, but an adverb.

Comment: IMO either "that it does in the U.S." or "as in the U.S."

Comment: They're grammatically different structures. But the linked question/answer explains that, as well as citing Swann's Practical English Usage which says both are OK. I'm unsure what you want that's not already covered - something specific to this case that's not in "the same book"?

Comment: This is really a fact about the constructions that _same_ can be  used in. _The same X as Y_ is interchangeable with _the same X that S_, where S is some tensed complement. If Y is a clause, too, _as_ can be used: _the same mother as Sam_ = _the same mother that Sam had_. But if Y isn't a clause, you can't use _that_.

Comment: Making that change would be purely your own style choice. In this case, 'as' and 'that' are interchangeable. If you're reviewing technical writing, what does your house style guide say?